# Why isn't the StackOverflow logo pixel-aligned?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I know this question may be a little bit useless, but **pixel-aligning things** — at least for me — **is something important.** I'm highly perfectionist and I see the Stack Overflow logo almost every day for about two months now, and I simply can't ignore the fact that the logo text isn't pixel-aligned. I don't even know how the old-school users can still look at it!  Why isn't the Stack Overflow logo pixel-aligned?

The Meta Stack Exchange logo **is** pixel-aligned, by the way.

**Here's the Stack Overflow logo "f":**

[image: StackOverflow logo "f"]

[image: StackOverflow logo "f" scaled up and surrounded by a red circle]

**Here's the same character — but pixel-aligned:**

[image: Pixel-aligned version of the Stack Overflow logo "f" character]

[image: Pixel-aligned version of the Stack Overflow logo "f" character scaled up]

Comment: How on earth did you notice that tiny difference?

Comment: Related discussion on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198821/why-is-one-stack-piece-in-the-stack-overflow-logo-slightly-off

Comment: "I don't even know how the old-school users can still look at it!" Because most of us are developers and not designers?

Comment: @Sam As I said, I'm highly perfectionist. Also, if you are using a high-DPI screen the problem becomes less visible.

Comment: @PeeHaa Weirdly I've added this phrase to the question, but deleted it later (I don't know why) during the edit: **"Being a programmer don't prevent you from thinking as a designer do."**

Comment: I guess I failed my vision test...the 'f' in the logo looks exactly the same to me on both sites.

Comment: The above statement about programmers thinking as designers only result in ugly designs and broken UX in my experience :P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot even in the scaled-up images? Are you using a high-DPI monitor?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot He said the Meta Stack **Exchange** logo is pixel-aligned, not Meta Stack Overflow. Both the Stack Overflow logos are not pixel-aligned.

Comment: @animuson Oops, I guess I failed my reading test, too. O_O

Comment: Robot, (AKA Martinho Fernandes), coded it.

Comment: I think it's just because the average person will not notice (or care). So why take the effort to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed when the images were switched to SVGs. See for example Meta's logo (in screenshot form):

[image: Meta logo]

Stack Overflow's logo is pretty much the same:

[image: Stack Overflow logo]

Comment: Well, on my 72dpi monitor with the logo "scaled down" it continues to be not pixel-aligned, but anyway it's SVG so this isn't important — because SVG doesn't depend on pixels, but vectors instead.

Comment: Apparently I don't have as sensitive eyes as you, @Tiago. ;) Sorry 'bout that -- but yeah, doesn't really matter.